# Saving an image using a Web Service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, web

I have a screenshot that I have got from the browser through the javascript code converted into string (type). I need Web Service that could read this string and convert it into image on the server side.

The question is:

How should I make a web Service that would be posible to read the string from browser and convert it into image to the server side.

Below the code is shown

```
package com.myfirst.wsServer;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

@WebService
public class ConvertToImage {
/**
     * Convert input string image to image
     * @param imageDataString
     */

public static void StringToImage(String imageDataString){

    try {
        // Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array
        byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imageDataString);

        // Write a image byte array into file system
        FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("D:\\" + getNewFileName() + ".png");

        imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);

        imageOutFile.close();

        System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

/**
 * Encodes the byte array into base64 string
 *
 * @param imageByteArray - byte array
 * @return String 
 */
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);
}

/**
 * Decodes the base64 string into byte array
 *
 * @param imageDataString
 * @return byte array
 */
public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
}

/**
 * Generate uuid an convert to String
 * @return uuid.toString()
 */

public static String getNewFileName(){
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    return uuid.toString();
}
}
```

Any questions or suggestions are welcomed
Thank you

PS: If you could help me and you are interested in javasvript code I can share it.

Comment: But you're already on the server here. Why transmit it again?

Comment: I don't transmit it again, just I read the string from client (browser) using the web service